# windows vista auto logoff issue

Tags: windows-vista

In my office workstation installed with Windows Vista, it logs out and goes to password prompt after 15 mins of idle time, as configured in my screen-saver settings.

In the password prompt, the password does not seem to match up with the corresponding user name and domain and says "Invalid username/password".

Whats wrong here? I can login after reboot, and do manual logout and login, with the same password against my username/domain configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Your office network use a domain? In that case make sure that you are using a domain account instead of a user account.

For example, if you computer is named `DESKTOP6` and the domain is `OFFICE` make sure that the full username is `OFFICE\USERNAME` instead of `DESKTOP6\USERNAME` (the login dialog usually shows the full user name below the input boxes).